# I want to add products in cart with custom labels on cart page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have tried several methods to add products to cart programatically but i want to show the quote item labels as well one cart page. Can anyone help me to do this or any references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code you are looking for;)

```
<?php

    $loadProductData = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $OrderquoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item');
    $quoteItem = $OrderquoteItem->setProduct($loadProductData);
    //custom options to show user on cart page
    $a_options = array(
      'options' => array(
         'label' => 'OptionLabel :',
         'value' => "OptionaValue",
      ));
        //add above options array to this cart item which is going to get added on cart
    $quoteItem->addOption(array(
          'code' => 'additional_options',
          'value' => serialize($a_options),
      ));
     // set price and quantity
    $quoteItem->setQuote($quote)
        ->setQty($productOptions['qty'])
        ->setOriginalCustomPrice($productOptions['price'])
        ->save();

    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code in your observer.

```
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item); 

        $additionalOptions = array(array(
             'code' => 'option_code',
             'label' => 'Some_option_Label',
             'value' => 'Option_Value'
        ));
        $item->addOption(array(
             'code' => 'additional_options',
             'value' => serialize($additionalOptions),
        ));

        // Enable super mode on the product.
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```